# Remove "role=banner" from HTML of react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, header, accessibility

I'm getting an accessibility error that tells me that the "banner landmark is contained in another landmark." In my case, it's in the header, which looks something like this:

`<header role="banner" class="pf-c-page__header">`

However, this header renders from an imported react component called `PageHeader` , for which the return method starts like this:

```
return (
    <header role="banner">
    ...
```

Is it possible to stop the banner from rendering just by modifying the JavaScript where I use the component? I don't think I am able to change the actual component.

e.g. can i add something here that would remove the "role=banner" HTML attribute?

```
    return (
      <PageHeader
      />
```

Comment: Only if the component has an API to expose that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you putting this header?

If you're putting it inside another landmark (such as `<nav>` or `<main>`), that would explain the error. You're allowed to put a `<header>` inside `<main>` but you should only use `role='banner'` for site-wide content, and `<main>` will always contain content specific for a given page.

Or perhaps the header itself is being treated as a landmark? It's not usually correct to add a landmark role attribute to a semantic element. And a `<header>` is treated as landmark role `banner` under certain circumstances, as [W3 mentions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#elementdef-header):

> Assistive Technology may convey to users the semantics of the header
>   element when it applies to the whole page. This information can
>   provide a hint as to the type of content. For example, the role of the
>   element, **which in this case is "banner"**, can be announced by screen
>   reader software when a user navigates to a header element that is
>   **scoped to the body element**. User Agents may also provide methods to
>   navigate to a header element scoped to the body element.

**(emphasis mine)**

So, the semantics of `<header>` may be identical to the semantics of the `banner` role.  Therefore, if your `<header>` is scoped to the **page** (rather than a section within a page), `role=banner` is unnecessary and should be omitted.

Conversely,  if the header is scoped to a **section** within a page, it is (by definition) not 'site wide content', and therefore `banner` role shouldn't be there either.

So it's simply incorrect to have `role=banner` on **any** `<header>` element. You might contact the author of the component and point this out!

You **can** remove attributes on the fly with `removeAttribute` - there are some caveats using this method with Internet Explorer - where you may have to set the attribute to "" before removing it.

However, in general, it's safer not to mess about with role attributes once they are set. Assistive tech might get confused if you do. There might be a way to remove the attribute from the element in react, before rendering. That would be best.

If you still want to have a go at removing the attribute with javaScript after the element has been rendered, I suggest you do it as soon as possible after rendering, and test properly across all target platforms and assistive technologies.

Better still, contact the author of the component, and ask them why they're always putting that role on there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The specs states for [role="banner"](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#banner) that you can have multiple `banner` elements assuming you have nested `document` (or `application`) subsections:

> Because `document` and `application` elements can be nested in the DOM, they may have multiple `banner` elements as DOM descendants, assuming each of those is associated with different `document` nodes, either by a DOM nesting (e.g., `document` within `document`) or by use of the `aria-owns` attribute.

So you can insert your react component inside a nested `document` tag

```
<body>
 <header role="banner" class="pf-c-page__header">...</header>
 <div role="document">
    <header role="banner">...</header>
 </div>
</body>
```

This does not mean that the tool you are using for testing your accessibility will correctly handle it.

Comment: `role=document` would never be a direct descendent of another `document` - the ARIA spec indicates that the document role should be used in the context of a widget or application role, since its primary function is to get the screen reader to switch (back) to 'browse mode' when 'applications mode' is on. It's hard to imagine a use case where any nested document would need **site-wide** content, although I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @brennanyoung The [ARIA spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#document) talks about when switching browsing mode is useful, which is not the question here. A simple use case of nested documents is an `iframe` or a web component, which is the question here.